# My application update checks harm the server performance

Tags: php, web, hosting

I have an application that checks for updates at every startup, and to do this it connects to the server (or website) to check if there's an update available.

The problem is that i have a lot of users, and when they check for updates the server suspend my account, and say (Daily hits limit accessed), even after upgrading or changing the provider.

Please, can someone tell me what can i do about this?

Comment: Have you tried any solution like upgrading your hosting plan with more bandwidth per day or switch to a different provider? If so please add and edit in you question.

Comment: Yes, I did, i tried two providers and both have almost the same daily hits limit

Comment: Release an update to your application which makes it check for an update less frequently? Once your users update, the problem should go away.

Comment: That's what i did, but i'm sure it's not the best solution

Answer (score 0):

One way you can cut down on the number of the hits is by re-examining this:

> an application that checks for updates at every startup

It might be an overkill if a single user starts it up many times a day.
If you measure it, you may figure out why you have this problem and devise a strategy.

Some example strategies (or their combinations) may be:

- on start up of application, if it already did the check today, don't do it again
- on start up of application, if there already was a check in the past X days, don't do it again
- on first start up of application, schedule when the next update check is due

**Edit**:
The solution to the server side is upgrading your providers' service or changing the provider to one that doesn't limit the daily hits or at least charges reasonable ammount for the extra hits.

Considering the cost, the strategies above look more reasonable.

Comment: This solution came to my mind, but i need a server side solution